# JedisSentinelPool is thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, redis

I know that jredis is not thread-safe, the Internet should be said that the use of JedisSentinelPool, it is thread-safe, but I use, the discovery is not the case, I do not know whether the use of a problem.

```
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Redis.class);
private JedisSentinelPool pool;

private static Redis instance = null;
public static Redis getInstance(){
    if (instance == null) {
        throw  new RuntimeException("Do not initialize!!!");
    }
    return instance;
}
public static void buildInstance(Map conf) {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (Redis.class) {
            instance = new Redis();
            instance.init(conf);
        }
    }
}

private Redis() {}

private void init(Map conf){
    JedisPoolConfig config = new JedisPoolConfig();
    config.setMaxIdle(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(conf.get("redis.max_idle"))));
    config.setTestOnBorrow(Boolean.valueOf(String.valueOf(conf.get("redis.isTest"))));
    config.setMaxTotal(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(conf.get("redis.maxTotal"))));
    String node = String.valueOf(conf.get("redis.node"));
    int timeOut = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(conf.get("redis.timeout")));
    String[] addressArr = String.valueOf(conf.get("redis.server")).split(",");
    Set<String> sentinels = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String str : addressArr) {
        sentinels.add(str);
    }
    pool = new JedisSentinelPool(node, sentinels, config, timeOut);
}

private Jedis getRedisTemplate() {
    Jedis resource = pool.getResource();
    return resource;
}

/** public */void setValue(byte[] key, byte[] value) {
    Jedis jedis = null;
    try {
        jedis = getRedisTemplate();
        jedis.set(key, value);
        closeJedis(jedis);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        closeBreakJedis(jedis);
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [B
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryBulkReply(Connection.java:216)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBulkReply(Connection.java:205)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.hget(Jedis.java:622)
    at com.mapbar.flash.common.cache.Redis.getHashValue(Redis.java:300)
    at com.mapbar.flash.common.cache.TerminalCache.getCityCodeArray(TerminalCache.java:35)
    at com.mapbar.flash.core.bolt.ElectronicFenceBolt.doExecute(ElectronicFenceBolt.java:106)
    at com.mapbar.flash.core.bolt.ElectronicFenceBolt.doExecute(ElectronicFenceBolt.java:1)
    at com.mapbar.flash.core.bolt.BaseBolt.execute(BaseBolt.java:79)
    at backtype.storm.topology.BasicBoltExecutor.execute(BasicBoltExecutor.java:49)
    at com.alibaba.jstorm.task.execute.BoltExecutors.processTupleEvent(BoltExecutors.java:183)
    at com.alibaba.jstorm.task.execute.BoltExecutors.onEvent(BoltExecutors.java:161)
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueueImpl.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueueImpl.java:191)
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueueImpl.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueueImpl.java:159)
    at com.alibaba.jstorm.task.execute.BoltExecutors.run(BoltExecutors.java:137)
    at com.alibaba.jstorm.callback.AsyncLoopRunnable.run(AsyncLoopRunnable.java:95)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The code from above does not fit the stack trace. `Jedis` itself is not thread-safe and must not be used concurrently across multiple threads but `JedisSentinelPool` is thread-safe with the pattern of allocating/using/releasing the pooled `Jedis` instance within the same Thread. If you require a different pattern, take a look at the [lettuce Redis client](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce) that is thread-safe without requiring pooling.

Comment: 3q，i found is my code problem,in a method i return the jredis before query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is my code problem,in a method i return the jredis before query.